# Using Instead-Of SQL triggers to insert or update a view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to write a trigger to the view, `VW_BANKBRANCH`:

- If the inserted row contains a `bankcode` that exists in the table, then update the
  `bName` column of bank table with the inserted data
- If not, insert rows to bank table to  reflect the new information.

But my trigger is not working..

**My tables**

```
CREATE TABLE bank(
  code VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  bName VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE branch(
  brNum INT PRIMARY KEY,
  brName VARCHAR(50),
  braddress VARCHAR(50),
  bcode VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES bank(code)
);

CREATE VIEW VW_BANKBRANCH
AS
  SELECT code,bname,brnum,brName
  FROM bank ,branch
  WHERE code=bcode
```

**My trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_VW_BANKBRANCH_INSERT ON VW_BANKBRANCH
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @insertedBankCode INT
    @insertedbname varchar
    @insertedbrnum int
    @insertedbrName varchar

SELECT @insertedBankCode = code
FROM INSERTED

IF(@insertedBankCode=code)
  SET code=@insertedBankCode
bname=@insertedbname
    brnum=@insertedbrnum
    brName=@insertedbrName
ELSE
    insert(code,bname,brnum,brName)
END
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? It won't run at all? It won't produce the desired result? It won't compile? ...?

Comment: yes it doesnt produce desired outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've adapted the instead of trigger on the view below - I'm assuming you want to upsert both bank and branch accordingly (although note that the branch address is not currently in the view).

That said, I would be careful of (ab)using an instead of trigger on an `INSERT` to do upserts - this might not be entirely intuitive to the reader.

Also, remember that the `INSERTED` pseudo table could contain a SET of rows, so needs to be adjusted to set based approach accordingly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_VW_BANKBRANCH_INSERT ON VW_BANKBRANCH
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE b
        SET bname = i.bname
        FROM bank b
            INNER JOIN inserted i
            ON i.code = b.code;

    UPDATE br
        SET
            br.brName = i.brName,
            br.braddress = NULL -- TODO add this to the view
        FROM branch br
            INNER JOIN inserted i
            ON br.bcode = i.code
            AND br.brNum = i.brNum;

    INSERT INTO bank(code, bname)
        SELECT code, bname
        FROM inserted i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 FROM bank b WHERE b.code = i.Code);

    INSERT INTO Branch(brNum, brName, braddress, bcode)
        SELECT brNum, brName, NULL, code
        FROM inserted i
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1 
                     FROM branch br 
                     WHERE br.bcode = i.Code AND br.brNum = i.brNum);

END;
GO
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e9be/2) - I've also adjusted the view to use a JOIN, rather than the old style of WHERE joins.

If you have SqlServer 2008 or later, you could also use [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) instead of separate inserts and updates.

Comment: Glad I could help! I hope you don't mind - I changed the title of your question - possibly this will help others in future.